# How to remove warnings of nullable in Android?

Tags: android, annotations, android-annotations

I'm using annotations library supported by Android. 
It is useful for checking NullpointerExceptions.
But, it also annoying if I checked the variable if it is null.

In this case:

```
@Nullable
String value;

boolean isValid(String target) {
    return (target != null && target.length() > 0);
}

void test() {
    if (isValid(value)) {
        Log.d("TEST", value);
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

In above code, I already checked if 'value' is null, but still got the warning of "It maybe produce NullPointerException".

Is there some annotations that I checked null-type in this function?

Comment: u can use assert  target != null above the return statement

Comment: Why not initialize the String `value` to an empty string in the constructor or at declaration itself?

Comment: add `@SuppressWarnings`

Answer (score 2):

**You can use the annotation:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
```

Answer (score 1):

In android studio Go to

file-->other settings---> default settings (defaultpreference)--->inspections--->java---> @notnull and nullable Probelms

**uncheck it** and click ok.